# Hide all links except for one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to hide all links except for one in javascript? (jquery is okay)

Say I have the following:

```
<div id="choices"> 
  <div><a href="#">A<></div> 
  <div><a href="#">B</a></div> 
  <div><a href="#">C</a></div> 
</div>
```

I want to make it such that if a user clicks link A, B, or C, the div's that do not contain the one that was selected disappear and the choice selected pops up in an alert box. Upon clicking on a reset button, all the divs appear again as normal.

Example: User clicks A, results in B and C divs hiding. User kicks Reset button and all show up again.

How do I accomplish this?

NOTE: I have been assigning IDs to each of the A, B, C divs respectively and made a function where when the user clicks B, it calls a $(divnotclicked).hide() for the ones I want to hide. And for the reset button I just do .show() for each of them $(A).show(), $(b) $.show()(C).show().... but theres gotta be a way to do with without me assigning IDs to each of them. Im looking for the best way to do it.

Im looking for the best way to do this, preferably without manually calling functions for each of them or assigning IDs to each div within the "choices" div. Or having to call on each individual div to ".show" upon clicking the Reset button.

Comment: I have been assigning IDs to each of the A, B, C divs respectively and made a function where when the user clicks B, it calls a $(divnotclicked).hide() for the ones I want to hide. And for the reset button I just do .show() for each of them $(A).show(), $(b) $.show()(C).show().... but theres gotta be a way to do with without me assigning IDs to each of them. Im looking for the best way to do it.

Comment: Are you interested in pure javascript, or jquery will do as well?

Comment: For the future: **always** describe what you've tried. People will be more eager to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, it's quite simple:

```
$('#choices div').click(function() { $(this).siblings().hide(); });
$('#resetButton').click(function() { $('#choices div').show(); });
```

Also, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zs8k/) with this code in action. In general, jsFiddle is an excelent tool when you need to play with jQuery (or other frameworks, for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

Just get all links and remove the one that was clicked using the `not` method:

```
$('#choices a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the click from activating the link
  $('#choises a').not(this).parents().hide();
  // do something with the chosen link
});

$('#reset').click(function(){
  $('#choices a').parents().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give each link its individual id. and add the same class to all of them For example:

```
<a class="mylinks" id="link01" href="someURL">friendly text</a>
```

then, when someone clicks on one of your buttons, set the css-visibility of the class to hidden, and then set the visibility of the id that belongs to the button to visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$('#choices a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().hide();
});
```

And for the reset:

```
$('#resetButton').click(function() {
    $('#choices div').show();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/W9Sym/

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
<div id="choices"> 
    <div><a href="#">A</a></div> 
    <div><a href="#">B</a></div> 
    <div><a href="#">C</a></div> 
</div>
<button>Reset</button>
```

to hide the containing divs of those not selected and have the reset show them, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kSTaZ/)

```
$(function() {

    $('#choices').on('click', 'a', function() { //bind click handler to choices, for links
        $(this).parent().siblings().hide();     //find the others and hide them
    });

    $('button').on('click', function() {        //bind click to button
        $('#choices > *').show();               //show all children of choices           
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:
HTML

```
<div id='A'>Hi, I'm A</div>
<div id='B'>Hello</div>
<div id='C'>Aaargh!</div>

<a href='#A'>A</a>
<a href='#B'>B</a>
<a href='#C'>C</a>

<button type='reset'>Reset</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('a').click( function() {
   var show = $(this).attr('href');
   $('div').each( function(e) {
       $(this).not(show).hide();
   });
   e.preventDefault();
});

$('button').click( function() {
   $('div').show();
});
```

Kind of verbose, but it should get the job done.

Comment: There are simpler solutions in this topic :)

Comment: Totally. They weren't there when I posted, though. :) Also, I didn't even get the question right. LOL.